# Launching an activity from an activity other than the main

Tags: android, android-activity, launching

I am new to android app development. I am practicing some basics with a simple app. I was able to launch an activity from my app's home screen, however, when I try to launch a third 
activity from activity2 using the same method, the app fails to work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fish);

    Button anthiasButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.anthiasButton);
    anthiasButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FishActivity.this, AnthiasActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kdc.reeffishguide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.FishActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fish" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.CoralActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coral" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.InvertsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inverts" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.AnthiasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_anthias" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am trying to open AnthiasActivity from FishActivity. No errors or warnings are given in eclipse, but when I run the app and click on FishActivity the app closes. When I delete the portion of code in fish activity that is responsible for launching anthias Activity, fish activity opens, but obviously I cannot get to Anthias Activity

```
package com.kdc.reeffishguide;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class AnthiasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anthias);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new     PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anthias, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anthias,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

here are the logcat errors.

```
04-12 19:24:32.427: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(22517): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No     such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-12 19:24:36.421: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(22517): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No     such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-12 19:24:40.425: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(22517): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No     such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you post some specifics? What is the error? Is there a stack trace in log cat?

Comment: can you post your mainfest

Comment: Looks like you had forgot to declare the new 3rd activity in the manifest.

Comment: please post complete code for more elaboration. Or add some more explanation about what you have done. and u have not mentioned about errors.

Comment: Add code of class  AnthiasActivity.

Comment: What does "fails to work" mean? What happens when you try this? If you get "Unfortunately App has stopped", you need to check the LogCat for what exeception was thrown.

Comment: by fails to work I mean that it launches the main activity, however, the second activity won't launch when clicked on even though it works when I don't include the 3rd activity's code within it. I just get a black screen and then it quits to the home screen.

Comment: Logcat error: No such file or directory

Comment: Please post the full logcat so that we can help you. In particular, what line does the error point to?

Comment: Those are not the logcat errors relevant to the failure.

Comment: **when I try to launch a third activity from activity2 using the same method, the app fails to work.** But you have no such code in activity2 (which am guessing you mean AnthiasActivity?) to **launch a third activity**)

Comment: There are three activities in this order; MainActivity, FishActivity, and then AnthiasActivity. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: once check in androidmainfest file.whether u have added FishActivity and AnthiasActivity  or not